# Is there an authentic hadith where a woman is forbidden from leaving the house while her father dies, but they're forgiven for her obedience?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, husband-wife

From [ImamReza.net](http://imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=6186) we have the following hadith (listed as by [Hojjat al-Islam Shaykh Husain Ansariyan](http://www.imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=4744)):

> Imam Sadiq said: One of the men from the Helpers (Ansar) went on a trip and ordered his wife not to leave the house until he returned home. Her father got ill while her husband was away. She sent a messenger to the Prophet (S.A.W.) asking him if she could visit her father. The Prophet (S.A.W.) replied that she should obey her husband and stay at home. Her father got worse and she sent another message but received the same reply. Her father passed away and she sent another messenger to go and pray for her father, but she received the same reply. They buried her father but the woman stayed at home. The Prophet (S.A.W.) sent a messenger to her and he said that God forgave you and your father for obeying your husband.

I also found it included at [erfan.ir](http://www.erfan.ir/english/14454.html), at [duas.org](http://www.duas.org/family/20.htm), and in a comment at [BabyCenter.com](https://community.babycenter.com/post/a40997218/husbands_permission_to_leave_the_house).  I've seen hadith with this meaning mentioned before (a woman is forbidden by her husband from leaving the house as her father dies), but I can't seem to pinpoint a reliable reference currently.

**Question**: Is there an authentic hadith where a woman is forbidden from leaving the house while her father dies, but they're forgiven for her obedience?

Comment: From a fiqh perspective: Maliki's and Hanafis would reject such hadith, shafi'i's would accept it saying it is preferable to leave her go, hanbalis would accept it as is.

Comment: That was only about one woman in particular, but I don't think it applies to all the other women.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hadith is included in *One Hundred Weak or Fabricated Traditions* by Shaykh Ihsan Al-‘Utaibi ([pdf](https://d1.islamhouse.com/data/en/ih_books/single/en_One_Hundred_famous_Hadith_Weak.pdf)).  It is described as:

> 41 - ((There was once a certain man who set out on a journey after having covenanted with his wife not to leave their house. Her father was downstairs, and she was upstairs. When he (her father) fell ill, the woman sent for the Messenger of Allah asking his permission to go down to see her father. The Messenger of Allah said, 'Obey your husband.' The father died. She sent to Prophet Mohammed once again [to get permission to see her father], but he said again, 'Obey your husband.' Her father was buried. The Messenger of God sent a message to her that her father was forgiven on account of her obedience to her husband)).

In this work, it's classified as weak:

> **Weak**; Al-Haythami said: [it is] narrated by Al-Tabari in "Al-Awsaat", and in it (i.e. the chain) is 'Aismah ibn Al-Mutawakil and he is weak. Al-Albani said: narrated by Al-Tabari in "Al-Awsaat" from the way of 'Aismah ibn Al-Mutawakil … and he is weak, and his shaykh Zafir ibn Sulaiman Al-Quhistani is also weak. Also narrated by 'Abd ibn Hameed (1369), from another way, but in the chain is Yousif ibn 'Atiyah and he is Matrouk, "Irwaa' Al-'Galeel" (7/76), and "Majmaa' Al-Zawaid" (4/313)