# Is it allowed for a women to uncover her face if non Muslim government banned face cover?

Tags: women, hijab, clothing

I'm living in a Buddhist country .. recently our country faced a terror attack so after that incident government banned women face covering

Comment: There's no consensus about face covering being a duty of a Muslim lady.

Answer (score 3):

Basically a Muslim is not allowed to live under non-Muslim leadership unless he has some reasons to do so (among these valid reasons you may find: work, trade, studies).

Secondly there's no harm (for a Muslim) in following the rules made by a non-Muslim government if they don't ask him to do something haram. Else a Muslim must consider leaving this country to keep his faith.

As stated in the comment even if some scholars (mostly from the hanbali madhhab) disagree face covering is not a duty for a Muslim lady. There's no single verse in the qur'an nor any hadith that actually orders it.
If the prophet () and the (male) sahabah met or spoke with women they  usually showed their faces or he () could directly look at their faces and he () never rebuke or ordered them to hide it, but he () also -as it seems- never asked a woman who covered her face to show or lift it. This tinny evidence is that of those saying that women must cover their faces and they may add that the times have changed compared to the time of the early Muslims.

See also:
- [Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5607/are-women-required-to-cover-their-face-and-palms-in-islam?rq=1)
 - [Covering Face In The House](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/covering-face-in-the-house?rq=1)
 - [Does a Muslim woman need to cover her entire body (including hands and face) during prayer if a non-mahram man can see her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35874/does-a-muslim-woman-need-to-cover-her-entire-body-including-hands-and-face-dur?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -3):

Salamo alaykom,

Covering the face for women is not an obligation in Islam.